# Is any package or jar file required for Lancet in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Programmin Clojure by "Stuart Halloway" book talks about Lancet, Very first step is **(use 'lancet)** which is throwing some Exception,

Exception
**user=> (use 'lancet)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate lancet__init.class or lancet.clj
 on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)**

Is any jar file or some package is required to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [lancet](https://github.com/stuarthalloway/lancet) installed to use lancet. I'm surprised the book doesn't mention anything like that. Anyway, I would strongly recommend you use [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) instead. Lancet is out of date and leiningen is the most popular build tool for clojure these days.

Comment: IIRC a lot of programming clojure actually walks through writing Lancet. So I guess the OP just jumped in at a random page...

Comment: @AdrianMouat I am learning step by step. Page 23 of this book is the conatins first step to build LANCET. Tell how to make this happen?

Comment: @vikbehal, I don't have the book with me or I'd look it up, but I'm sure it's explained somewhere. You just need to add the code from somewhere. Anyway, Joost is right, you're best off persevering with lein.